# Why I cannot save my template's content in my postgres database?

Tags: python, django

I have a model to rate a rented car in my Django project. However, when I submit the template's content, it seems that they are saved in the database but when I check in my data base, the table is empty.
I've check all my code, I cannot find the error.
Please, here are my model, views, the urls and my template respectively.

Model:

```
class tb_CARS_COMMENTS(models.Model):
    SCORE_CHOICES = zip(range(6), range(6) )
    nom_client = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    vehicule = models.ForeignKey(tb_CARS, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    qualite = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, blank=False)
    prix = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, blank=False)
    confort = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, blank=False)
    conduite = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SCORE_CHOICES, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    site_web = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    Commentaires = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Évaluation(Véhicule ='+ str(self.vehicule)+', Qualité ='+ str(self.qualite)\
        +', Prix ='+ str(self.prix)+', Confort ='+ str(self.confort)+', Conduite ='+ str(self.conduite)+')'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='COMMENTAIRE'
        verbose_name_plural='COMMENTAIRES'
```

The views:

```
def AddComment(request):
    detail=get_object_or_404(tb_CARS_CONDITIONS,id=id)
    form=CARS_COMMENTForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Hello chef')
            obj, created = tb_CARS_COMMENTS.objects.update_or_create(
            vehicule=detail.vehicule_id,
            nom_client=request.GET.get('nom_client'),
            qualite=request.GET.get('qualite'),
            prix=request.GET.get('prix'),
            confort=request.GET.get('confort'),
            conduite=request.GET.get('conduite'),
            email=request.GET.get('email'),
            site_web=request.GET.get('site_web'),
            Commentaires=request.GET.get('Commentaires')
            )

        else:
            print('We are not reaching here')
            
    context={
        }
    return render(request,'Cars/comments.html', context )
```

The urls:

```
app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HompePage, name='home_page'),
    path('about_page/', views.AboutPage, name='about_page'),
    path('contact_page/', views.ContactPage, name='contact_page'),
    path('service_page/', views.ServicePage, name='service_page'),
    path('liste_voiture/', views.ListeVoiture, name='liste_voirute'),
    path('vehicule/<int:id>/detail/', views.DetailsVoiture, name='vehicule_detail'),
    path('addComments/', views.AddComment, name='add_comments'),
]
```

The template:

```
<!-- Car Review Form-->
    <div class="rn-review-form">
                    <h2 class="rn-simple-title">Rédiger un commentaire</h2>
                    <form action='' method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
                                <div class="rn-rating-input rn-rating-input-quality">
                                    <label>Qualité:</label>
                                    <div class="rn-rating-input-inner">
                                        <input name="qualite" class="rn-rating-value-input" type="hidden"/>
                                        <div class="rn-rating-main-input"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
                                <div class="rn-rating-input rn-rating-input-price">
                                    <label>Prix:</label>
                                    <div class="rn-rating-input-inner">
                                        <input name="prix" class="rn-rating-value-input" type="hidden"/>
                                        <div class="rn-rating-main-input"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
                                <div class="rn-rating-input rn-rating-input-comfort">
                                    <label>Comfort:</label>
                                    <div class="rn-rating-input-inner">
                                        <input name="confort" class="rn-rating-value-input" type="hidden"/>
                                        <div class="rn-rating-main-input"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
                                <div class="rn-rating-input rn-rating-input-driving">
                                    <label>Conduite:</label>
                                    <div class="rn-rating-input-inner">
                                        <input name="conduite" class="rn-rating-value-input" type="hidden"/>
                                        <div class="rn-rating-main-input"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Nom complet" name="nom_client">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="url" placeholder="Site web optionnel" name="site_web">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Test" name="test">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Redigez votre commentaire" name="Commentaires"></textarea>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <input class="btn btn-main btn-lg btn-shadow" type="submit" value="Envoyer">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <!-- End Car Review Form-->
```

Hopefully you will find where I've have made the mistakes.

Comment: I don't think you liek to use `update_or_create()` here. This will lead to new entries if any value you assigned will differ to an existing database entry. As far as I understand your code, you could just use `create()`, as there should be no case where you like to update an existing row.

Comment: You are missing the `id` in the URL pattern for add comments. Something like `path('vehicule/<int:car_id>/addComments/', views.AddComment, name='add_comments'),` and then use it as parameter for your view like `def AddComment(request, car_id):` and in the next line `detail=get_object_or_404(tb_CARS_CONDITIONS,id=car_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to add the car ID to your URL patterns and the `AddComment` view.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/

Second I would suggest to display the form error messages, to see if the input is valid or if there are any issues.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Third you should use `create()` instead of `update_or_create()`, as you like to add new comments if the form was sent and not update existing ones.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Assigning the `ForeignKey` value instead of the related object

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

```py
app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HompePage, name='home_page'),
    path('about_page/', views.AboutPage, name='about_page'),
    path('contact_page/', views.ContactPage, name='contact_page'),
    path('service_page/', views.ServicePage, name='service_page'),
    path('liste_voiture/', views.ListeVoiture, name='liste_voirute'),
    path('vehicule/<int:id>/detail/', views.DetailsVoiture, name='vehicule_detail'),
    path('vehicule/<int:car_id>/addComments/', views.AddComment, name='add_comments'),
]
```

```py
def AddComment(request, car_id):
    detail=get_object_or_404(tb_CARS_CONDITIONS,id=car_id)
    form=CARS_COMMENTForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Hello chef')
            obj = tb_CARS_COMMENTS.objects.create(
                vehicule_id=detail.vehicule_id,
                nom_client=request.GET.get('nom_client'),
                qualite=request.GET.get('qualite'),
                prix=request.GET.get('prix'),
                confort=request.GET.get('confort'),
                conduite=request.GET.get('conduite'),
                email=request.GET.get('email'),
                site_web=request.GET.get('site_web'),
                Commentaires=request.GET.get('Commentaires')
            )
        else:
            print('We are not reaching here')
            
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request,'Cars/comments.html', context )
```

```html
<!-- Car Review Form-->
<div class="rn-review-form">
    <h2 class="rn-simple-title">Rédiger un commentaire</h2>
    <form action='' method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!-- error reporting -->
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {% for field in form %}
          {% if field.errors %}
            <p class="alert alert-danger">{{ field.errors }}</p>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <!-- ... rest of your form template -->

    </form>
</div>
<!-- End Car Review Form-->
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I noticed that the issue is with the vehicule as foreignkey. If I remove it from the model it is saving successfully. If a keep it in the model it is not saving the form's content. But it has not to be like that because the comment has to be related to a car. When we see a comment we must know to which car is it related.

Comment: I've updated the answer to fix the issue with the `ForeignKey` issue and assinging an ID instead of the object. Just adjust the line to `vehicule_id=detail.vehicule_id`